# MySQL insert with auto increment

Tags: java, mysql

Im trying to insert some data from my application into my database, but I keep getting the error stated below.

I have 4 columns in my table and one is set to auto increment. I suspect that is causing the error.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Table Columns:

```
Id (auto increment), userID(generated from application), username, name
```

Code:

```
    String sql = "insert into details values (?, ?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, userID);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, name);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); 

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was just a simple human error. Wrote the execute statement twice.

```
    String sql = "insert into details values (?, ?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, userID);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, name);

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); <-- Changed to preparedStatement.execute();

    preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql); <-- Removed this line
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
insert into details (userID, username, name) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Hi did you mean:String sql = "insert into ratings (id, username, rating) values (?, ?, ?)";? It didnt work.

Comment: I'm not sure about your schema (your question is a bit unclear). Notice though the syntax in my answer. You need to specify the columns for which you want apply data in your insert.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your sql-statement to this:

```
String sql = "insert into details (userID, username, name) values (?, ?, ?)";
```

Because you do not add all attributes of the table you have to say which arguments you add.

Comment: @user3702643 Is userid in db an int?